# C# code convert into VB.Net (Generic)

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string str;
    string[] s = Array.ConvertAll<DataRow, string>(dt.Select(), delegate(DataRow row)
    {
        return (string)row[""];
    });
    str = String.Join(",", s);
```

Comment: The question is so well-phrased, I'm speechless...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like following:

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim str As String
    Dim s As String() = Array.ConvertAll(Of DataRow, String)(dt.Select(), Function(row As DataRow) DirectCast(row(""), String))
    str = String.Join(",", s)
```

In case of `VB 8.0 (.Net 2.0)`, it does not support anonymous methods. To workaround that, use following code:

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim str As String
    Dim s As String() = Array.ConvertAll(Of DataRow, String)(dt.Select(), AddressOf ConvertRowToString)
    str = String.Join(",", s)
```

`ConvertRowToString` function:

```
    Function ConvertRowToString(ByVal row As DataRow) As String
        Return DirectCast(row(""), String)
    End Function
```

Comment: It give syntax error "Experssion Excepted" in Function keyword

Comment: @Cody Gray: VB.NET is not my first language. :)